# vim, any way to copy'n paste, using the mouse, without using shift

Tags: vim, mouse, x11, copy-paste

I'm used to most X11 apps that copy'n paste with a simple middle mouse key.  In vim I must remember to hold the shift key.  Is there any way in vim to copy'n paste using the mouse without the shift key?

Comment: You only need to hold shift with certain mouse settings, such as mouse=a.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to get the vim with the GTK2-GNOME GUI libs.

before the Ubuntu Karmic install was
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.2 (2008 Aug 9, compiled Sep 21 2009 11:25:46)
Included patches: 1-245
Compiled by buildd@crested.buildd
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):

now the version is 
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.2 (2008 Aug 9, compiled Sep 21 2009 11:22:21)
Included patches: 1-245
Compiled by buildd@crested.buildd
Huge version with GTK2-GNOME GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):

Now the left mouse button selects and pastes in to X apps.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you don't need the shift key if you're in insert mode.

Edit: Actually, I never need to hit shift.